# Excel - Return specific values if condition if met, textjoin array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I'm working on an Excel doc and really scratching my head about a problem I have.

I have 2 worksheets, Main and Report.

The formula I'm looking for is to search the relative candidate name in the report, search for any 'complete' courses, and return the course name(s), leaving out any which are not complete.

So far, I have got closest with this formula:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(Report!E:E="Complete",IF([@[Candidate Name]]=Report[Candidate Name],Report[Course Name],""),""))`

However for some reason, this will return the course name from the cell BELOW the completed course. Not sure if this is due to the nested IF statement.

Any help would be much appreciated!

### HOW I WANT THE OUTCOME TO LOOK

MAIN

| Candidate Name | Course | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Safeguarding, Data Protection, | COMPLETE |
| Ben | Safeguarding | COMPLETE |

REPORT

| Candidate Name | Course | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Safeguarding | COMPLETE |
| Alex | Data Protection | COMPLETE |
| Ben | Safeguarding | COMPLETE |
| Ben | Data Protection | Not Started |

Comment: The table references used in your formula don't seem to match the example table headers. Should the example headers be changed or your formula? Also you use full column reference and table reference in the same formula, which are arrays of different lengths.

Comment: I've just corrected the formula name to match the table example I gave below. -- I include the title[column header] because the data was downloaded from a folder. Not sure if this makes a difference?

Comment: And if you change `Report!E:E` into `Report[STATUS]`?

Comment: Hurrah! That's done it! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You were pretty close. `Report!E:E` range is a much longer range than `Report[STATUS]` which results in an error or not true.

Comment: You could also write it like `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF((Report[Candidate Name]=[@[Candidate Name]])*(Report[STATUS]=[@STATUS]),Report[Course],""))` (Ctrl+shift+enter for older Excel versions). I. Office 365 you could also use FILTER: `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(Report[Course],(Report[Candidate Name]=[@[Candidate Name]])*(Report[STATUS]=[@STATUS]),""))`